# Specializing a struct in two variants

Tags: c++

I need a `struct` with two specializations:
One if `std::atomic<T>::is_always_lock_free` is `true` and `sizeof(T) == sizeof(std::atomic<T>)` and another which is just empty.

Do I have to use `enable_if` ?

Comment: I'm curious about the added requirement `sizeof(T) == sizeof(std::atomic<T>)`. Why?

Comment: Absent concepts, that's typically the tool you'd use. However, considering the relationships you're trying to test, it sounds like one of your specializations is going to be doing some shenanigans (ie: `reinterpret_cast`ing one to the other), so you might want to rethink them.

Comment: I've got patented a mostly lock-free algorithm which isn't lock-free under some circumstances. F.e. if there's a shared value (of templated type) for which atomic<T>::is_always_lock_free is true and sizeof(T) == sizeof(std::atomic<T>), then I cast the T* pointer to an atomic. But because of the strict aliasing rule I want to make it a bit cleaner and have a union of the value-type (for non-lockfree accesses) and a templated struct which is derived from one of the above specialisations, depending on if the type has the same size and it is always lock-free.

Comment: I hope you won't be doing any type-punning through your union, as it's not allowed in C++. Only the last written-to member can be read from.

Comment: @BonitaMontero Have you found a lock free `atomic` where `sizeof(T) != sizeof(std::atomic<T>)` ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: In theory ...

Comment: @TedLyngmo: It's just to be safe.

Comment: Using type-punning through unions leads to undefined behavior. Even if it works on all modern PC-like systems I would not trust any code with UB.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: In theory ...

Comment: In theory it works fine until you need to compile your code on some not so common target platform where the compiler does not allow it as extension and you wont notice until it blows up

Comment: That will never happen.

Answer (score 0):

This is called Class template SFINAE

https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/class-template-sfinae.html

```
template <typename T, typename Enable = void> 
class foo{
// general case
}; 

template <typename T> 
class foo<T, 
  std::enable_if_t<std::atomic<T>::is_always_lock_free and (sizeof(T) == sizeof(std::atomic<T>))>
>{ 
// specific case
};
```